# count the number of files copied recursively using aws cli commands

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Could someone help me with the command to count the number of files only copied from one parent object to another parent object. For example

```
1. src/folder1/some1.txt    
2. src/folder1/folder1_1/some1.txt
3. src/folder2/folder2_1/some2.txt
4. src/folder4/folder4_2/some3.txt
5. src/folder4/folder4_1/some4.txt
```

copy over them to `dest` folder

So, when I do

aws s3 cp  s3://src/* s3://dest/ --recursive

I need a count of the number of files copied.

Comment: does it have to be a raw cp command or would you take a solution that uses `find` or `for` loop?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I have to use cp only, It is a part of project wherein I need a count of the number of files copied given folder locations.Thanks

Comment: Is dest going to A) be empty? OR B) never contain files with the same name as the ones being copied?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, dest does contain the same name as the ones being copied but the idea is to overwrite them.

Comment: That makes it harder to count the number of files you copied, unless you are OK with checking timestamps.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, yes any approach is fine. Could you kindly help me on this. Thanks

Comment: Your question is 100% clear, so before I do that, I need to get some details straight.

Comment: So can you use `rsync` instead of `cp`? Same functionality, but very parseable output if you specify the right set of flags.

Comment: You can use the `-v` option to make it print a message for every file it copies. Then pipe to `wc -l` to get the number of lines.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, actually I am working on aws and they have sync command which looks similar http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Comment: You should really try to put a complete set of details into your question...

Comment: When you have fleshed out what it is exactly you are trying to do, I will write up a couple of options that I have in mind, or perhaps someone else will.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I know but I was interested to see if there is a command as such using cp. I edit the question accordingly

Comment: Oh wait, just do `cp -Rv ... | grep ??? | wc -l`. `???` is probably going to be `->` or something else that determines that a line describes a copy rather than an informational message.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, nope, nothing on aws side. At the max, these messages . The source folder is s3://vineshdummy01/folder3/ and the destination folder is s3://amp/playarea/dinesh/folder1/

Answer (score 3):

Lets say we have mp3 files in a S3 bucket with the following path:
`bucket-name/path/to/files`
Then the cmd `aws s3 ls bucket-name/path/to/files --recursive | grep 'mp3' | wc -l`
will output the count of all mp3 files in that path even if they are present within directories.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is to rely on the fact that `cp -v` prints each file that it copies in a format like `` `source' -> `dest' ``:

```
cp --recursive --verbose s3://src/* s3://dest/ | grep -F '->' | wc -l
```

`grep` will output something for each line where `->` is found, and `wc` will count the lines, which will give you the total number of copies made.

Comment: nope, nothing on aws side. At the max, these messages:-  "upload: ../../../../tmp/BashPlayArea2/s3:/dineshdummybucket01/folder3/sample1.txt to s3://amp.de.data/playarea/dinesh/folder1/sample1.txt"